# scopeBar don't show under UISearchBar when it is active for the first time

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I programmatically created a UISearchController, and set the scope button titles in viewDidLoad

```
UITableViewController *searchResultsController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
searchResultsController.tableView.dataSource = self;
searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self;
[searchResultsController.tableView registerNib:musicNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MusicCell"];

self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
UISearchBar *searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar;
searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[@"Album", @"Artist", @"Song"];
searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex = 0;
searchBar.delegate = self;

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
```

But when I search in search bar when view loaded. the scope bar don't show up. The second I search in search bar, the scope bar shows. What's going on?

[image: first time search, scope bar don't show]
[image: second time search, scope bar shows]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
searchBarDisplayController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = NO;
searchBarDisplayController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = nil;
```

Based on your comment, put the above code in searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch: delegate method. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
searchController.delegate = self

// in the delegate...

func willPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
}

func willDismissSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = false
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 16 and upper try this:

```
searchController.scopeBarActivation = .onSearchActivation
```

Answer (score -2):

You can remove `searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;`